# Power BI Data Gateway - Azure VM v On-Premises

Tags: powerbi

When you have a SQL Server instance running in an Azure VM and you want to connect Power Bi Data Gateway to it, do you install the Data Gateway or is there another way for Power BI to get the data, considering it isn't technically "On Premises"?

Comment: Once your VM is Azure, it means that it is on cloud. So there is no point in considering it as On-Premise I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For connections to it from Power BI Desktop, you can connect to it via the IP Address or instance name if you have extended out your physical network to Azure or the IP/Firewall is configured to allow access direct to the VM.

A gateway will be needed to be installed on the VM (or another VM in the network that can see the VM hoisting SQL Server) for the Power BI Service to connect to the data source when you load your report to the service.

If you were connecting to Azure SQL Database, you would not need a gateway

From the [Power BI Community Website](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/SQL-Server-hosted-on-Azure-VM-Do-I-need-a-Gateway/td-p/489761), response is from a community moderator

> You are connecting to a SQL Server that hosted in Azure VM but not
>   Azure SQL database in Power BI Desktop. For the former, gateway is
>   required, you can install gateway on the same machine with Power BI
>   Desktop, then add SQL Server data source within the gateway.
>   Otherwise, you are not able to view the published report in Power BI
>   Service.

Another mention is on the following site

https://radacad.com/the-power-bi-gateway-all-you-need-to-know

Comment: Thanks, Jonee, that was exactly my thought too, but I can't find any supporting documentation to back this up. Are you aware of anything?

Comment: I know I've seen it on the MS Doc's website, but can't find the ref, I've added a URL for decent source. I'll update the answer if I find the official docs

Comment: Haha, those are the same URLs that I've been looking at, strange that there's nothing official isn't there.